# Any way to bypass or spoof graphic card check?

Tags: windows, installation, graphics-card, graphics, integrated-graphics

I facing some problem with a software. While installing it's giving me a error that "you graphic card is not in the supported list please update you graphic driver".

My graphic driver are up to date .

Is there any method by which I could spoof my graphic card vendor or model no , may be some registry ke or a hack .

Edit:

The software I'm talking about is Bluestack ( Android Emulator ) .

Comment: You can give 3d-Analyze a try, but if your card isn't supported then it probably won't work anyway.

Comment: What card, what software are we talking about?

Comment: @vonbrand  It's Bluestack (android emulator)

Comment: I've seen a few older games that my hardware is too new for, and I've occasionally found hacked copies of DirectX dlls that trick the game into believing that the card is an older model. depends on what the community has to offer.